# Why do channels arise from "failing to record measurement outcomes"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-measurements

In Preskill's notes, the need for quantum channels began with the following situation: System A starts out in a pure state and interacts with system B, therefore forming a joint state of system AB. We then imagine measuring system B (the pointer) but fail to record the measurement outcomes, therefore, forcing us to take the final state being the sum of all post-measurement states weighed by their probability outcome.

My question is, what do we 'mean' by failing to record measurement outcomes? Is this a human error wherein we forget to record a measurement outcome, or is it something entirely different?

(Preskill's Lecture notes 3, page 11)
[http://theory.caltech.edu/~preskill/ph219/chap3_15.pdf](http://theory.caltech.edu/%7Epreskill/ph219/chap3_15.pdf)

Comment: You can consider to add a PDF link (as far as I remember the notes are available online, no?).

Comment: Yes, it is. I shall add the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I'd put it is that using channels is what you get when you want to describe the dynamics of part of a quantum state. In other words, there's a large quantum state evolving in the standard way via Schroedinger, but you only care about/have access to part of the state. This is therefore an "effective description" of the evolution.

Not having access to part of the system turns out to be mathematically equivalent to saying that that part of the system (which I'll refer to as the "environment" in the following) was somehow measured but we don't know the measurement outcomes.
This doesn't mean that there's necessarily actually someone measuring the environment. It means that the reduced dynamic on the system isn't affected by whether the environment was measured or not. By definition, we don't have access to the state of the environment, and thus won't know whether it was measured. As it turns out, it is often convenient to think of this situation as a measurement having been performed on the environment and us not knowing the outcome.

Another way to think about this is that we describe the reduced dynamics on the system in terms of what we'd get conditionally to someone measuring the environment and finding a specific outcome. Except we don't know the outcome and thus have to consider convex mixtures of these possibilities.

Comment: Why is the reduced dynamic of the system not affected by the measurement of the environment? If system A and the environment interact and build up correlations, wouldn't the measurement of the environment (somehow) even collapse the system A?

Comment: @PrathamHullamballi no, the act of measurement on its own does not affect the rest of the system, unless the measurement outcomes are sent over. This is true in general, look up the no-communication theorem

Comment: Oh, so basically, what you're trying to say is that measuring the environment collapses the environment and, therefore, the system A collapses as well, but the density matrix of A stays the same irrespective of what's done to the environment, entangled or not.

Comment: @PrathamHullamballi you can see it that way, yes. But thinking in terms of the reduced system density matrix, measuring the environment just has absolutely no effect. In fact, you can't know whether the system was measured without further information, so it makes more sense to just say that the state remains the same regardless of what happens on the environment

Answer (score 1):

Quantum mechanical systems interact with the environment. If they do so, we can think of the environment as effectively measuring the system -- formally, this is completely equivalent. However, the information is "hidden" in the environment, and we don't have access to it (and it is typically very hard to access it, as the information is "smeared out" over the $\sim 10^{23}$ degrees of freedom of the environment). Thus, we can think of this as "measuring and ignoring the outcome", i.e., averaging over all possible outcomes (with the respective probabilities).

Comment: Would a better phrase be that we know the system is /was measured, but we don't know the outcome/post measurement state? "Forgetting" the outcome seems to imply that we knew it at some time. Actually, how do we know *what* is being "measured"? I guess this is somehow related to the measurement problem?!

Comment: What do you mean by the environment effectively measuring the system? How does the environment measure the system?

Comment: @Tobias That's really more a question of perspective, interpretation, language ... formally, the math is all the same. If I way "measure but don't know the outcome", someone will claim (rightfully so!) that this is not a measurement, because the very point of a measurement it to learn the outcome. Maybe "measure and average over the outcome", that would be most accurate.

Comment: @Pratham 1) The math is the same as if it was a measurement, but we average over all outcomes. 2) Quantum physics is unitary, so the information must still be in the environment. So with a smart measurement of the environment, we can actually perform some effective measurement on the system.

Comment: @Pratham Regarding 1), in essence for a POVM you have a post-meas state $M_i\rho M_i^\dagger$, and if you average over all outcomes you get $\rho\mapsto \sum M_i\rho M_i^\dagger$, which is just a CPTP map, here the physical evolution of the system when coupled to the environment. Same maths.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch so basically, as the environment and system are coupled, measuring the environment (somehow) effectively allows us to measure the system it is coupled to as they're entangled. In this sense, failing to measure outcomes in Preskill's notes means measuring the environment without knowing the outcome (and therefore effectively measuring the system as well). This is what I understood.